# Compile ASP.NET MVC3 views to dll and check the use of properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, strongly-typed-view

I'd like to compile my ASP.NET MVC3 view to a separate .dll file using the RazorGenerator in Visual Studio 2012.

My question is: How can I check which properties are used in the view?

My model:

```
public int PproductID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

And [my result](http://pastebin.com/KUUNuFFf) from RazorGenerator.

In the view I don't used all properties so How can I check with the reflection that I use?

Comment: It's not a small problem.  I think you would have to run a parser on each view to find out.

Comment: Why does it matter?  Are you wanting to remove properties from your model that aren't in the view?

Comment: The idea is that if in the future I would like to save it to a database I do not want to enter any unnecessary records.

Comment: I think you might be prematurely optimizing.  What's in the views shouldn't drive the database design.  If anything, the opposite is true.

Comment: OK. But for myself. How to compile the resulting code. Dll and pull it all the properties? But only with the code, not the model class.